# How do i add a git repo based plugin to my npm install for ionic framework?

Tags: angularjs, git, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using the Ionic Framework with AngularJs to make a web application.  Now that i have a bunch of my application in place with static information, I wanted to now update the services to leverage database.  I was looking up the best course of actions for databases with the ionic framework and angular.  I was told that Sqlite would be the best option.

I ended up at the following website from my search: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/11/use-sqlite-instead-local-storage-ionic-framework/ which was mentioning to me to run: `cordova plugin add https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin.git`.

My first attempt of running the command seemed to update a lot of my files under the *platforms/* directory of my application which I thought was odd.  I was not sure if i should be adding them to my repository or not.

Anyways the question I am getting at is.  I want to run an npm install on my machine and everything would be good to go for whoever pulls my code.  How would I had this plugin git website so when the install runs, it will then run this file.

**EDIT** I was not sure if it was as simple as adding the URL to the cordovaPlugins list in the packages.json file.  I am going to test that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you add plugins, you can add the `--save` flag to the cordova/ionic command to save them to your package.json. That way when someone pulls in your project, they can run `ionic state reset`, which causes ionic to install all the cordova plugins from the package.json file.

Comment: so, does that mean that i should add the `"script":{"postinstall":"ionic state reset"}` to my package.json file, so after i run an `npm install` it will auto run the state reset?

Comment: If you are attempting to run the command automatically using only `npm install`, then yes you should be able to add `"scripts":{"postinstall":"ionic state reset"}` to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best way but what I did was:

created a script file in `scripts/setup.js` which carried the following code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

//This script will add or remove all plugins listed in package.json
//usage: node platforms.js [add | remove]

var command = process.argv[2] || 'add';
var packageJson = require('../package.json');

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

packageJson.cordovaPlatforms.forEach(function(platform) {
  var platformCmd = 'cordova platform ' + command + ' ' + platform;
  exec(platformCmd);
});


//Set up Plugins.
var command = process.argv[2] || 'add';

var packageJson = require('../package.json');

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

function createAddRemoveStatement(plugin) {
  var pluginCmd = 'cordova plugin ' + command + ' ';
  if(typeof plugin === 'string') {
    pluginCmd += plugin;
  } else {
    if(command === 'add') {
      pluginCmd += plugin.locator + ' ';
      if(plugin.variables) {
        Object.keys(plugin.variables).forEach(function(variable){
          pluginCmd += '--variable ' + variable + '="' + plugin.variables[variable] + '" ';
        });
      }
    } else {
      pluginCmd += plugin.id;
    }
  }

  return pluginCmd;
}

function processPlugin(index) {
  if(index >= packageJson.cordovaPlugins.length)
    return;

  var plugin = packageJson.cordovaPlugins[index];
  var pluginCommand = createAddRemoveStatement(plugin);
  console.log(pluginCommand);
  exec(pluginCommand, function(){
    processPlugin(index + 1);
  });
}

processPlugin(0);
```

This file would then check the cordovaPlatforms section and cordovaPlugins sections for things which need to be added and then add them.

I then went into *packages.json* and added:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall":"node scripts/setup.js"
}
```

and then after the npm install finished, it would then run the set up script which would add all the required platforms and plugins accordingly.